# Error: [$injector:undef] Provider '' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn AngularJS. Whdile I was following the instructor, I wrote the same code as he did. But I am getting a `Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'eliteApi' must return a value from $get factory method.` . When I searched for this error in web, it is told that I must return a function or an object. I guess I am doing it. My factory declaration is below:

```js
angular.module("eliteApp",["ionic"])
.factory('eliteApi', function() {

  function eliteApi(){

    var leagues = JSON.parse('"name": "Spring Fling Tournament 2014","id": 2009,"homeScreen": "* 5th Grade Championship - 7:30m MAC 3\n* 6th Grade Championship - 6:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade White Championship - 7:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade Green Championship - 7:30pm MAC 2\n* 8th Grade Championship - 7:30pm MAC 1\n* 9th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 4\n* 10th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 1\n* 11th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 3","rulesScreen": null');


      function getLeagues(){
        return leagues;
      }



    return {
      getLeagues : getLeagues 
   };
  };
  
})

.controller('LeaguesCtrl', [ '$scope','eliteApi', function($scope, eliteApi) {



  function LeaguesCtrl(eliteApi){
    var vm = this ;
    var leagues = eliteApi.getLeagues();
    };

}])
```

Any helps are appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `factory` to this:

```
.factory('eliteApi', [function() {

 return {
          getLeagues : function(){
                           var leagues = JSON.parse({"name": "Spring Fling Tournament 2014","id": 2009,"homeScreen": "* 5th Grade Championship - 7:30m MAC 3\n* 6th Grade Championship - 6:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade White Championship - 7:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade Green Championship - 7:30pm MAC 2\n* 8th Grade Championship - 7:30pm MAC 1\n* 9th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 4\n* 10th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 1\n* 11th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 3","rulesScreen": null});
                           return leagues;
                       }
        }
}])
```

See if this works.

**UPDATE**

your variable `league` is not a proper `JSON`. Change it to

```
 var leagues = JSON.parse({"name": "Spring Fling Tournament 2014","id": 2009,"homeScreen": "* 5th Grade Championship - 7:30m MAC 3\n* 6th Grade Championship - 6:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade White Championship - 7:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade Green Championship - 7:30pm MAC 2\n* 8th Grade Championship - 7:30pm MAC 1\n* 9th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 4\n* 10th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 1\n* 11th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 3","rulesScreen": null});
```

You forgot the `{}`. Also remove the quotes`'`.

Comment: Thanks , your solution works but just when I change var leagues ="hello"; but when i do var leagues = JSON.parse(...); it gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: @halloausdeutschland. Thats bcoz what you are parsing using `JSON.parse` is not JSON. See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

@Sourabh-
thank you for ur help,
this is the solution:

```js
.factory('eliteApi', function() {
 var leagues1 = JSON.stringify({"name": "Spring Fling Tournament 2014","id": 2009,"homeScreen": "* 5th Grade Championship - 7:30m MAC 3\n* 6th Grade Championship - 6:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade White Championship - 7:30pm MAC 4\n* 7th Grade Green Championship - 7:30pm MAC 2\n* 8th Grade Championship - 7:30pm MAC 1\n* 9th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 4\n* 10th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 1\n* 11th Grade Championship - 8:30pm MAC 3","rulesScreen": null});
var leagues = JSON.parse(leagues1);

    return {
      getLeagues :    function getLeagues(){     
   return leagues;
        }
    };
  })
  
 .controller('LeaguesCtrl', [ '$scope','eliteApi', function($scope, eliteApi) {

    var leagues = eliteApi.getLeagues();
       var leagueData = eliteApi.getLeaguesData();

  
})
```